# I don't understand why my code isn't working

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning javascript and have made a small little program to create an alert when a button is clicked, yet it doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: grey;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        const some_action = () => {
            window.alert("hi")
        }
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", some_action)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <button id="btn">click me</button>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The script is being executed before the button has been initialized in the body.

Comment: Yep, move the script to the bottom of the page

Comment: place the `<script>`  tag after your `<body>`.

Comment: Get used to opening the browser's debugger console, and you'd see a more useful error message that you can use for your own research.

Comment: Either move it to the bottom or use a window.onload method

Answer (score -2):

Or, alternatively, you could do a delegated event attachment:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: grey;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        const some_action = ev => {
            if (ev.target.id === "btn") window.alert("hi")
        }
        document.addEventListener("click", some_action)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <button id="btn">click me</button>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```